Is it possible to grouping packages dependencies using tuist for bettter project organization?
Is it possible to organize SPM package dependencies, which are usually placed in the "Packages" group (group or folder in Xcode project), into sub-groups or sub-folders using Tuist?

Not as of Tuist 4.12.1.
First lets deffriate the two ways to consume Swift Packages in Tuist.

Vanila directly in the Project.

let project = Project(name: "You Project Name",
                      packages: [...],
                      targets: [...]

....


Using combination of Package.swift + Tuist external dependencies - link

// Package.swift file
#if TUIST

import ProjectDescription
import ProjectDescriptionHelpers

let packageSettings = PackageSettings(
    productTypes: // define custom types for products,
    targetSettings: // define custom settings per target per package,
    projectOptions: // define custom options per package,
)

#endif

let package = Package(
    name: "PackageName",
    dependencies: [
.package(url: "https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk", .upToNextMajor(from: "17.0.0")),
.package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", exact: "10.23.1"),
    ]
)

// Project.swift file
let project = Project(name: "You Project Name",
                      targets: [...])
In each target you define an SPM dependency using .external("FirebaseCrashlytics")
....


You are describing the vanila usage of packages with Tuist. It is recommended to utilize Package.swift file to consume external (i.e SPMs) - link.
To answer your question - NO. (true for Tuist 4.12.1)
All local packages will go under the Packages folder in the generated project/workspace. All external Packages will appear as regular SPM products
